# How to Trim of the spaces(right side) in this Array?

Tags: c, arrays, trim

Hello i have a problem with solving a Programing Task in C.

> The funktion "Trim" should replace all spaces at the end of a String
>   with null. As parameter it gets a string but it dosent need to return
>   anything.
>
> The second funktion "countSpaces" should count all spaces in an Array.
>   As parameter it gets a 2 dementional Array and it should return the
>   number of spaces in the Array.
>
> Other Headers arent allowed.

Orginal in German:

> Die erste Funktion Trim  soll alle Leerzeichen am Ende einer Zeichen-
>   kette löschen (d.h. mit dem ASCII-Wert 0 überschreiben). Als Parameter
>   wird die Zeichenkette übergeben. Die Funktion gibt nichts zurück.
>
> Die
>   zweite Funktion  countSpaces  soll alle Leerzeichen in einem Array von
>   10 Zeichenketten mit je maximal 50 Zeichen zählen. Als Parameter erhält
>   es  ein  zweidimensionales Array   von  Zeichen. Das  Funktions-ergebnis
>   ist die Anzahl der Leerzeichen in allen Zeichenkette des Arrays von Zeichenketten.
>
> Weitere Headerdateien sind nicht erlaubt

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char Text[10][50] = {"Dies ist ein langer      ",
                        "Text, der in mehreren    ",
                        "Zeilen untergebracht     ",
                        "ist und der auch noch    ",
                        "in manchen Zeilen mehrere",
                        "Leerzeichen am Ende      ",
                        "beinhaltet! Die Leer-    ",
                        "zeichen dieses Textes    ",
                        "sollen gezählt werden!   ",
                        "                         "};
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Trim(Text[i]);
   printf("\nIn dem Text sind %i Leerzeichen enthalten!\n",
           countSpaces(Text));
}
```

UPDATE:
thats where i stand now, thx to the awnsers of u guys i am now here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  mystrlen(const char *str);
void *Trim(char *str, int ch);
int countspaces(const char *str);


int main()
{

   char Text[10][50] = {"Dies ist ein langer      ",
                        "Text, der in mehreren    ",
                        "Zeilen untergebracht     ",
                        "ist und der auch noch    ",
                        "in manchen Zeilen mehrere",
                        "Leerzeichen am Ende      ",
                        "beinhaltet! Die Leer-    ",
                        "zeichen dieses Textes    ",
                        "sollen gezählt werden!   ",
                        "                         "};
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {

       Trim(Text[i], ' ');
       printf("Number of spaces after trim: %d\n", countspaces(Text[i]));
   }
}


int mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;

    while(*end++);

    return end - str - 1;
}


void *Trim(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *end = str + mystrlen(str) - 1;

    do
    {
        if(*end == ch) 
        {
            *end = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(str != end--);
    return str;
}

int  countspaces(const char *str)
{
    int  count = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        count += *str++ == ' ' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It works so far.

Would it also be possible to Count the Spaces for the Whole Array?

Comment: homework? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't forget that `char` string in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. Changing one character to the null-terminator `'\0'` effectively terminates (and truncates) the string at that position.

Comment: And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: OT - homework. Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *remove_trailing_char(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    do
    {
        if(*end == ch) 
        {
            *end = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(str != end--);
    return str;
}
```

The full solution

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;

    while(*end++);

    return end - str - 1;
}


char *remove_trailing_char(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *end = str + mystrlen(str) - 1;

    do
    {
        if(*end == ch) 
        {
            *end = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }while(str != end--);
    return str;
}

size_t countspaces(const char *str)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        count += *str++ == ' ' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    size_t nspaces;
   char Text[10][50] = {"Dies ist ein langer      ",
                        "Text, der in mehreren    ",
                        "Zeilen untergebracht     ",
                        "ist und der auch noch    ",
                        "in manchen Zeilen mehrere",
                        "Leerzeichen am Ende      ",
                        "beinhaltet! Die Leer-    ",
                        "zeichen dieses Textes    ",
                        "sollen gezählt werden!   ",
                        "                         "};
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       printf("Number of spaces before trim: %zu\n", countspaces(Text[i]));
       remove_trailing_char(Text[i], ' ');
       printf("Number of spaces after trim: %zu\n", countspaces(Text[i]));
   }
}
```

And play with it yourself https://onlinegdb.com/H1p13QDXE

Comment: hmmm sadly that didnt help me, i tryed to make a "void trim" funktion out of this and failed :/

Comment: @ArchDoge Changing the return type should not matter. The function simply returns a pointer to the string you pass as argument. How did you call it and how did it fail? Since no other header files are allowed I guess you should not use `strlen` but implement a replacement yourself.

Comment: If the ready made function did not help - you need to start from the C book.

Comment: i am actually sitting here with a codebook and like 2 million open tabs to the topic and still dont get it....sorry for being new to C

Comment: Thx for the full solution i am still trying to understand it but that may take some time, i play around with the code a bit.

Comment: Also would this be possible without changing the main funktion?